# Controlling image bandwidth issues on a community site

Tags: php, .htaccess, bandwidth

I am working on a community photo sharing site, and I need some way of controlling the bandwidth. For example I would like to set a maximum bandwidth allowed, which can be **image size** x **the number of times the image was viewed**. Similar to what a site like photobucket does (when they replace an image with a bandwidth exceeded image).

I am wondering what the best solution would be. **How can I track the number of times an image is viewed?** Maybe I need to use something like Google Analytics and then run a cron job every so often to see if any image has exceeded the bandwidth limit? I think this may be overkill and I am over thinking this problem.

By the way, I am developing in PHP.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok, so it seems mod-rewrite is the way to go. Right now I have the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ /include/image.php
```

When I go to an actual image (i.e. http://...picture.jpeg), the PHP page image.php loads, but **when an image is in an img tag** (i.e. img src=http://...picture.jpeg ), the image does not load (good), but **the php file does not load in its place**.

How do I fix it?

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

If anyone is interested, this worked (although it can probably be improved):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*).(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|wbmp)$ /include/image.php?location=$1&format=$2 [NC,L]
```

If you look at the $_GET variables image.php is receiving, you can probably figure out what to do from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are keeping a database of images, and details. Could you not store requests to images in your database? If the number of requests for a certain day exceed *n*, you refuse the image.

Going this route would mean you would have to serve all images through a PHP script, as opposed to letting people have direct access to the image itself. Using mod_rewrite with apache, you could rewrite all requests for `images/001830.jpg` to `images/serve.php?id=001830` which would allow you to perform checks against the stored data to determine if you output the real image, or a generic "bandwidth exceeded" image in its place.

Comment: Right, but how do I know if an image was requested?

Comment: Serve all images through a PHP script.

Comment: Thats the simplest solution but it can mess a bit in performance when traffic became bigger. Anyway its a good idea for start (read about mod_rewrite - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Could you write an example of this mod_rewrite, I'm having some trouble with it..

Comment: Domenic, you should start a second question. This is an entirely different topic now :) Please consider accepting my answer, and be sure to let us know the URL of the *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter in your database and add 1 to it every time a user looks at an image, you can also sort the date and time, if the last view was a prior day reset the counter to 1.